# UncheckedIOException is thrown instead of a different expected exception

Tags: java, oop, exception, refactoring, cactoos

While refactoring [Rultor](https://github.com/yegor256/rultor) to use [Cactoos](https://github.com/yegor256/cactoos) instead of [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava), I’m having an issue with negative tests of [`GithubProfileTest`](https://github.com/yegor256/rultor/blob/5f2e7fa8f6fee577719239933068fb048a175fc9/src/test/java/com/rultor/profiles/GithubProfileTest.java) and `GithubProfileValidationTest`.

After the refactor, the positive test cases pass for both mentioned test classes, but the negative test cases that expect a particular exception fail.
The affected refactored code under test is `GithubProfile.assets` method and `GithubProfile.asset` method.

I refactored `assets` method to look like this:

```
 public Map<String, InputStream> assets() throws IOException {
    final XML xml = this.read();
    final List<XML> nodes = xml.nodes("/p/entry[@key='assets']/entry");
    return new MapOf<>(
        new Mapped<>(
            nodes,
            input ->
                new MapEntry<>(
                    input.xpath("@key").get(0),
                    this.asset(input.xpath("text()").get(0))
                )
        )
    );
}
```

On different test cases the `this.asset` call is expected to throw `Profile.ConfigException`. Instead, upon calling the assets method, the test fails with a `Unable to evaluate the expression Method threw 'java.io.UncheckedIOException' exception`, and the `Profile.ConfigException` is simply ignored/hidden.

It seems that `MapOf` somehow fails to evaluate, or "hides", the exception that the call to this.asset method raised, raising itself an `UncheckedIOException`, so I'm unable to fix this and have the `Profile.ConfigException` raised.

When debugging, the `UncheckedIOException` doesn't contain any info whatsoever of a `Profile.ConfigException` being raised.

Any hints on why I might be getting this behaviour or possible solutions?

Comment: The only line of code I see which can throw an `UncheckedIOException` here is your `read()` method. What does it do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `Iterable#next()` (in JDK) doesn't allow to throw checked exceptions (like `Profile.ConfigException`). That's why `org.cactoos.iterator.Mapped` catches them all and throws `UncheckedIOException` instead. It's unfixable, thanks to JDK design. The best you can do is good old `for` loop:

```
public Map<String, InputStream> assets() throws IOException {
  final XML xml = this.read();
  final List<XML> nodes = xml.nodes("/p/entry[@key='assets']/entry");
  final List<MapEntry> entries = new LinkedList<>();
  for (final XML node : nodes) {
    entries.add(
      new MapEntry<>(
        input.xpath("@key").get(0),
        this.asset(input.xpath("text()").get(0)) // checked exeption here
      )
    );
  }
  return new MapOf<>(entries);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason is probably the conversion done in `org.cactoos.func.UncheckedFunc` while iterating to populate the map.

Since functional style programming usually does not play very well with exceptions, the API tries to avoid declaring checked exceptions. So you probably have to live with that.